# Eclipselink tries to inset null value in table

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I'm currently trying to create a many to many mapping using eclipselink. Please note that for this specific example no table to resolve the relation is used (I kwon that this is not a good practice but it is necassary for this specific example).

I've created a database schema and the tables employee3 and insurance to map. The employee table holds a column called insurance_id which is part of the primary key in order to create the mapping. Same goes for insurance with employee_id.

Now for the code:

Here is the code for the two classes:

First off Employee:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee3", schema = "many_to_many")
public class EmployeeManyToMany
{  
  protected EmployeeManyToMany()
  {

  }

  @Id
  private int id;

  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  @ManyToMany(cascade =  CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private Collection<InsuranceManyToMany> insurance;


  public EmployeeManyToMany(int id, String firstName, String lastName)
  {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    insurance = new ArrayList<InsuranceManyToMany>();
  }
.....
```

And Insurance:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "insurance", schema = "many_to_many")
public class InsuranceManyToMany
{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private int insuranceId;
  private String company;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "insurance", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private Collection<EmployeeManyToMany> employee;

  protected InsuranceManyToMany()
  {
  }

  public void addEmployee(EmployeeManyToMany emp)
  {
     employee.add(emp);
  }

  public InsuranceManyToMany(String company, int insuranceId)
  {
     this.insuranceId = insuranceId;
     this.company = company;
     employee = new ArrayList<EmployeeManyToMany>();
  }
....
```

After I create an Employee object and add a list of insurances to it i try to persist it into the database. 
Which results in the following error:

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002]              
Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.3.v20180807-4be1041):    
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value 
in column "insurance_id" violates not-null constraint
Detail: Failing row contains (1, hans, test, null).
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO many_to_many.employee3 (ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES
(?, ?, ?)
bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(swd_ws18_06_Tag3.EmployeeManyToMany@88d98e)
```

I have no idea why this occures since the values are never null.

Any help is appreciated!

BR
Simon

Comment: Where did you map a many_to_many.employee3.insurance_id column? It isn't shown in your mappings at all, which would be why you don't get values inserted into it. Did you mean to setup a OneToMany relationship instead of a ManyToMany?  ManyToMany by default will use a relation table, while your table setup described has a 1:1 relationship from EmployeeManyToMany to the insurance object.

Comment: Hi! That could be the case! Do you have to define the relationtable in the java code or just on the database side? With the mapping you mean defining it by using a join collumn? I thought that was not necessary since the colmumn already exists i  the db? BR

Comment: You need it in the database for the columns, constraints, etc to be there, and then you need to tell JPA about it so it knows how to map your object model to the database.  Defaults are used if you don't have explicit columns, join columns etc defined, and in this case, isn't want you want JPA to be using, as the default for a ManyToMany is to use a relation table that you don't have.  Try something more like https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Relationship_Mappings/Collection_Mappings/OneToMany as I think it matches your DB more closely